# Use 2 ifs or if else if to check for 2 possible condition

Tags: c#, if-statement

Which of the following is preferable when checking two possible outcome to condition?

This one:

```
if (x == 2) {

}
else if (x != 2){

}
```

Or that one

```
if (x == 2) {

}

if (x != 2){

}
```

Comment: If you have a binary condition of `==` and `!=`, then neither. Use `if () {} else {}`

Answer (score 1):

When you use sequential if-statements, then *all conditions* get evaluated.

When you use `else if`, the *first matching conditional body* (including the first `if`) is entered, but all conditions up to that point will still be evaluated from top-to-bottom.

When you have conditions that only can have two cases, then you don't need `else if` , and can just use `else`

Comment: Unless I'm missing your point, not all conditions are evaluated when using `else if`. No conditions after the matching one are evaluated.

Comment: @Irpe Yes, all are evaluated from the top, but only  the first matching condition's block is entered, and none after

Comment: But if I have an `if` followed by an `else if`, and the `if` evaluates to true, then the `else if` is not evaluated, right?

Comment: @Irpe Correct, I am referring to the conditional block body entered first, not the `else if` itself. As answered, **all** conditionals are evaluated

Comment: But they're not? Only conditionals up to and including the first one that matches are evaluated. The rest are skipped.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet the `else if ( x != 2 )` that is the opposite is useless because the previous condition failed thus it is always true, therefore only `else` is needed.

For the same reason exposed above, the second version is a code smell because you check two times the value : you should only use this if you modify `x` in the previous test block otherwise it is a defect, or at least an opinion and a matter of preference that reduces the speed due to more IL opcodes, and therefore more machine code, and therefore more CPU ticks that is ~x2 on the condition line.

[C# - Decision Making](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_decision_making.htm)

[Boolean Algebra for Dummies](https://dev.to/stefandurlesteanu/boolean-algebra-for-dummies-nno)

[What is Boolean Logic?](https://www.lotame.com/what-is-boolean-logic)

[Boolean logic](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zqp9kqt/revision/1)

[Boolean Logic](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/71boolean)

[Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need second check? Just use else statement after first if statement.

Comment: One might want more than two possible outcomes.